# Solving an exponential inequality $4^x + 25^x + 0.01^x \lt 2$ without using logarithms

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I need to solve this inequality without logarithms , 10th class

> $$4^x + 25^x + 0.01^x \lt 2$$

I got $$2^{2x} + 5^{2x} + 0.1^{2x} <2$$ then $$5^{2x} + 0.1^{2x} < 2(1-2^{2x-1}),$$ so after this I realized that the left side is greater than $0$, and so $1-2^{2x-1}$ should be greater than $0$ , and by logic I got that $x$ is less than $0.5$.  This is all I could do.
P.S thank u all

Comment: What is the range for $x$ ? for $x \gt 0$ the inequality is wrong.

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit that's precisely the question.

Comment: I dont know dude , teacher asked us to solve this we of course asked himhow to solve this if we dont know exponential equations and inequalities , he said there is no need to know it in order tosolve this

Comment: @Tiko I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I have a solution as well; will undelete after seeing your thoughts.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg 
I tried really hard , i got 2^2x + 5^2x + 0.1^2x <2 
then 5^2x + 0.1^2x < 2(1-2^(2x-1)) , so after this i realized that the left side is greater than 0 , so 1-2^(2x-1) should be greater than 0 , and by logic i got that x is  less than 0,5 . this is all i could do

Comment: @AndrewChin I tried really hard , i got 2^2x + 5^2x + 0.1^2x <2 then 5^2x + 0.1^2x < 2(1-2^(2x-1)) , so after this i realized that the left side is greater than 0 , so 1-2^(2x-1) should be greater than 0 , and by logic i got that x is less than 0,5 . this is all i could do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By AM-GM
$$4^x+25^x+\frac{1}{100^x}\geq3\sqrt[3]{4^x25^x\cdot\frac{1}{100^x}}=3>2.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: That's rather attentive of you to recognize $4\times25=100$, bravo.

Comment: im really thankful great man

Comment: @Tiko You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The answer:  *no solution*.

At the 10th level, all you should be expected to know is:

- $a^m>0$ for $a>0$
- $a^m$ appears to increase if $a>1$
- $a^m$ appears to decrease if $0<a<1$.

Since you are summing powers with bases greater than $1$ and powers with bases less than $1$, there is no way for the sum of three powers to be less than $2$.  In general, if you are summing an $n$ number of powers that contain bases both greater and less than $1$, then the sum is always going to be greater than $n-1$.

For an extreme example, view a graph on Desmos [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/chlfvej39w).

Comment: im really thankful great man

Answer (score 0):

I think I realized how he wants you to do the problem but it is by no means obvious:

$4^x +25^x+10^{-2x} = 2^{2x}+5^{2x}+10^{-2x}= 2^{2x}+5^{2x}+5^{-2x}2^{-2x}$

Now let $u=2^{2x}$ and $v=5^{2x}$

Essentially you are solving the equation: 
$$ u+v +u^{-1}v^{-1} < 2 \Rightarrow u+v<2uv \Rightarrow u-2uv+v <0 \Rightarrow (u-v)^2<0$$

But this cannot be true for any real numbers u and v. Since I am assuming you are only searching for real solutions for x the same holds for $(2^{2x}-5^{2x})^2<0$

And as such there are no real solutions.

Comment: another variant of solving thank you